# ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path' in C#

Tags: c#, xml, filepath, argumentexception

The error I am receiving upon executing my code is: 'ArgumentException was unhandled. Illegal characters in path.'

I am using the following code to access my .xml file.

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CommandLine);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(appPath + @"\Books.xml");
```

I am doing this for a console application, as opposed to a WinForm. I have been exhaustively googling, as well as searching SO, for some time.

This is part of a homework project. This is the only problem I am running into however.

Comment: Print `appPath` to the console and see what it is

Comment: What is the path that you are passing in on the CommandLine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(appPath, "Books.xml"));
```

Comment: This will only work if the code above is in the exe, which is probably good enough. Don't do it from a DLL though unless it's in the same directory :)

Comment: Works great! Thank you! A note in case anyone comes across this solution...make sure to include 'using System.Reflection;' =P

Answer (score 1):

`System.Environment.CommandLine` does not return a path - it returns the value of the command line that was executed to run the application.

You probably need to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (as Furqan Safdar posted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752999/1583)) instead.

Comment: Be careful though. Current directory is not necessarily the same as the directory containing the executable file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - True, though I can't ever recall the recommended way to get the application path.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the EXE path returned by CommandLine is funky, so you need to do something like this:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.CommandLine.Trim('"', ' '));
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get application directory:

```
var rootDirectory = AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory;
```

Good luck!